# For loop not running as intended

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

Why is this giving me the value of `front_post_count = 3.0 instead of 4.0 ?

```
canopy_length=10000
front_post_count=ceil(canopy_length/3500)+1
for i=1 to front_post_count do
(
    print(front_post_count)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what maxscript is, but `10000/3500` might evaluate to an integer (2 in this case) and not to a float. Maybe try `10000/3500.0` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked! Maxscript is the scripting language for 3d studio max.